# Function that gets the working value of a buffer local variable

Tags: buffer-local

I want to write a function that gets the working value of a buffer local variable.  Customarily if a buffer local variables is not defined, it might have a default
value set up.

Comment: You can use `(with-current-buffer BUFFER VARIABLE)`.  If the variable is buffer-local, that buffer-local value will be returned.  If the variable is global, then the global value will be returned.  As mentioned in a separate thread recently, the default value of a variable can be obtained with the function `default-value`.

Comment: You don't need a function for that (assuming that you are "in" the buffer - i.e. that the buffer is the current buffer): you just reference the variable. @lawlist tells you how to get the value of the variable if the relevant buffer is *not* the current buffer (it will work for the current buffer too, but it's computationally more expensive and much less convenient than referencing the variable directly).

Comment: The documentation says that the forms in BODY are executed.  How can I work with `(with-current-buffer BUFFER VARIABLE)` for a particular variable?  In order to get the value.

Comment: "if a buffer local variables is not defined, it might have a default value set up." Why is that a problem - that **is** the value of the variable in the buffer (and everywhere else it doesn't have a buffer-local value). The question is unclear.

Comment: Because I want to get the value of a variable so I can store it.  Will be resetting the value temporarily and want to be able to toggle it to its original value.

Comment: When I set the variable `ramona-mode-line` using `(setq ramona-mode-line mode-line-format)` will it always be the one that is used?